# Python lxml out of memory while using iter in a for loop

Tags: python, xml, memory, lxml

I'm writing a solution in order to extract information from a file.
These files are generated in Windows Event Utility command via some other script (i'm not invoking, just receiving the file for parsing):

```
wevtutil qe Application /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='NameOfTheSourceApplication']]]" >> %FILE%
```

This command save all the output regarding the source application queried to a dump file, eventually there is a XML for each *event* on every line. All I care about is the `EventData` and `TimeCreated SystemTime`.

Example output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="" />
      <EventID Qualifiers="">0</EventID>
      <Level>4</Level>
      <Task>0</Task>
      <Keywords />
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-10-02T11:19:41.000000000Z" />
      <EventRecordID />
      <Channel>Application</Channel>
      <Computer />
      <Security />
   </System>
   <EventData>
      DATA
      <Data />
   </EventData>
</Event>
```

When the dumping the file is finished, the file could be quite large (above 6-7GB). So I'm using Linux `iconv` utility to change the source file encoding from `UTF-16/UCS2-LE` (default encoding of wevutil) to `UTF-8`, the new encoding reduces almost half of the file size. Then I'm using the `grouper` recipe combined with some simple file split function in order to split the big dump file to a smaller files:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
   """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"""
   # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
   args = [iter(iterable)] * n
   return zlg(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def splitter(fileobj,outName,ranoutName,rencode,wencode):
    with open(fileobj,"r",encoding='UTF-8',errors='replace') as f:
        for i, g in enumerate(grouper(n, f, fillvalue=''), 1):
            with open('{0}_{1}.xml'.format(i,outName), 'w',encoding=wencode) as fout:
                fout.writelines(g)
                print("Splitting file : %s" % (fileobj))
```

Since these files are not actually XML files but each line formatted as xml with namespace, I'm adding a root tag to each splitted file one by one, to be parsed by `lxml` later on (glst stands for "globbed list").

```
def rooter(glst):
    for logFiles in glst:
        oFile = open(logFiles,'r',encoding='utf-8')
        rFile = oFile.read()
        wFile = open(logFiles,'w',encoding='utf-8')
        wFile.write('<root>')
        wFile.write(rFile)
        wFile.write('</root>')
        oFile.close()
        wFile.close()

        print("Rooting XML : %s" % (logFiles))
```

Then I'm loading only one XML file to be parsed in `lxml`:

```
def loadXml(fileobj):
    tree = etree.parse(fileobj)
    print("Processing : %s" % (fileobj))
    return tree
```

Here comes my bottleneck, since i did not find any other convenient method to parse the file efficiently while I'm seeking only the `Event Data` and my `Event Time`. After finding the data, I'm appending my findings to two separate lists (one for the event data, one for the event time) which i later on convert to a simple CSV file, in order to continue my parsing via `pandas`.

This code actually works with files under 2GB, but run completely out of memory while parsing files above 2GB, my solution has to run in system which has only 2-3GB of free RAM (Windows 64-bit desktop).

```
def parser(tree,DataL,DataTimeL):
    for evts in tree.iter('{%s}EventData' % nameSpace):
        EvtData = evts.find('{%s}Data' % nameSpace).text
        DataL.append(EvtData)        
    for evtSysTime in tree.iter('{%s}System' % nameSpace):
        eSysTime = evtSysTime.find('{%s}TimeCreated' % nameSpace).attrib
        DataTimeL.append(eSysTime)
        break
```

I tried manually to `gc.collect` and `del` the file object after parsing but it's seems to have no effect and python keep building up memory until the PC is crashing.

```
def initParser(glst,DataL,DataTimeL):
    for file in glst:
     root = loadXml(file)
     parser(root,DataL,DataTimeL)
     gc.collect()
     del file
```

CSV Creation (zlg stands for itertools - zip_longest):

```
with open('LogOUT.csv', 'w', encoding="UTF-8", newline='') as cF:
    wr = csv.writer(cF)
    wr.writerow(("Event", "Event Time"))
    wr.writerows(zlg(EvtL,EvtTimeL))
```

I've tried using TinyDB, ZODB which sounds like an overkill, also it's too slow or maybe I am doing it wrong. Dumping the events to a CSV manually is very slow.
Since the `for` loop parser function is actually very efficient on files under 2GB, I would like to find a way to append these big list safely and efficiently without crashing the entire system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with generator/iterator expressions in Python? Instead of accumulating data inside a list/variable or reading a file completely, you can process it line by line (or whatever smallest unit of work is) without using RAM completely.

Comment: Hi, i'm a novice python programmer, i know about generator/iterator expressions and yield, just don't know how to reshape it in order to accomplish my goals which is basically parsing this big file in order to save a lot of manual work with text editors.

Comment: Use SAX in order to handle big files. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.reader.html and http://python.zirael.org/e-sax1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept that uses iterators to read a large file that consists of lines with self-contained XML and extracts specific fields into a CSV file. Modify it to suit your needs.

```py
import csv
import itertools
import typing
from io import StringIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element


def grouper(iterable, n, fill=None) -> typing.Iterator:
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fill)


def parse_event_xml(event_xml: str) -> dict:
    root: Element = ElementTree.fromstring(event_xml)
    namespaces = {'ns': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'}
    time_el = root.find('./ns:System/ns:TimeCreated', namespaces=namespaces)
    data_el = root.find('./ns:EventData', namespaces=namespaces)

    return {
        'Event Time': time_el.attrib['SystemTime'],
        'Event Data': data_el.text,
    }


def process_batch(batch: typing.Iterator[str], batch_filename: str) -> None:
    fields = ['Event Time', 'Event Data']
    with open(batch_filename, 'w', newline='') as bf:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(bf, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        for item in batch:
            if not item:  # skip empty lines
                continue
            parsed = parse_event_xml(item)
            writer.writerow(parsed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml_raw = '''<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name=''/><EventID Qualifiers=''>0</EventID><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords></Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2018-10-02T11:19:41.000000000Z'/><EventRecordID></EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer></Computer><Security/></System><EventData>DATA<Data></Data></EventData></Event>
    <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name=''/><EventID Qualifiers=''>0</EventID><Level>4</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords></Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2018-10-02T11:19:41.000000000Z'/><EventRecordID></EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer></Computer><Security/></System><EventData>DATA<Data></Data></EventData></Event>'''

    batch_size = 10  # lines / events

    # read the event stream
    # normally you'd use `with open(filename, encoding='utf-8')`
    # but here i'm reading from a string
    with StringIO(xml_raw) as f:
        for i, batch in enumerate(grouper(f, batch_size)):
            batch_filename = f'batch_{i}.csv'
            process_batch(batch, batch_filename)
```

Adjust `parse_event_xml` function to extract the data you need, here I've only used `EventTime` and `EventData`

this one outputs a csv file like this:

```
Event Time,Event Data
2018-10-02T11:19:41.000000000Z,DATA
2018-10-02T11:19:41.000000000Z,DATA
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - i will check that out, i probably will have some minor adjustment to do in my source code, i will try and keep you posted.

Comment: Hi, your solution is working exactly as i meant, thanks for your kind help, i will play with batch_size until i will find the best fit for my available RAM.

Comment: You might not even need to set a batch size if you only need a single huge CSV file.  This code should be able to handle any file of any size